# Recurring non-scheduled transactions in GnuCash

Tags: gnucash

Does GnuCash have a similar mechanism to MYOB where a transaction can be made into a template for posting when needed?

I can see a transaction can be made into a template for automated scheduled posting, but can't see how to "post now".

I've just been duplicating a previous instance of the desired transaction and changing the date, but sometimes a previous instance of the desired transaction isn't that quick to find.

Comment: I've just noticed if typing the same transaction description it will duplicate the last transaction with the same description, including the splits. Although that relies on remembering the description, I think the fast workflow with it trumps.

Comment: Nothing that I can think of.

Comment: @jontyc I think your comment is the answer. There is nothing wrong with you answering your own question. Please do so and accept that answer so this question no longer appears in the 'unanswered' list.

Comment: It would be very useful if a set of "job codes" could be input to gnucash that would allow for one to re-use an existing transaction with slightly different inputs. For example, if I was a contractor working on HVAC systems, I know that a job for installation of a specific A/C unit would be the same, regardless of the customer I'm installing it for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described in a comment to my question, typing in the same transaction description as previous has been the only way I've seen to duplicate a previous transaction.

The issue with this of course is finding what the previous transaction was called, but the autocompletion helps somewhat.

Answer (score 0):

I'm considering the same thing myself right now and I'm going to create dummy accounts for each template I need, 0 amount so I don't end up messing with anything, although a single dummy account for all of them could work too.  Then all you need to do is change the account name to the account you're actually after (and date/amount etc).  I'm excited!